# MoSKito: "advice defined in ... has not been applied"

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to use [moSKito](http://www.moskito.org/) monitoring tool to follow this [step-by-step guide](http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/). I've added those strings in `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
   <artifactId>moskito-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
    <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
         <aspectLibraries>
             <aspectLibrary>
                 <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                 <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
             </aspectLibrary>
         </aspectLibraries>
         <source>1.7</source>
         <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
         <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
     </executions> 
</plugin>
```

I also added Monitor annotation to collect statistics from my controller:

```
@Monitor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(...)
public class MyController { ... }
```

And when I am trying to deploy my war to tomcat, I get those warnings:

> Warning:ajc: advice defined in net.anotheria.moskito.aop.aspect.MonitoringAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
>
> Warning:ajc: advice defined in
> net.anotheria.moskito.aop.aspect.CounterAspect has not been applied
> [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Please describe why these warnings are appearing and how to make them disappear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonitoringAspect contains more than one annotation, in particular it contains @Monitor and @DontMonitor.
As long as you don't use all contained annotations, the plugin warns you (whether it makes sense or not, is another question).
Same for Counter.

The more important question though, is: are the classes showing up in the monitoring? Remember, you have to access them at least once, to see them in the MoSKito Inspect.

regards
Leon

Comment: You're right, it is written in this guide that you should see this string:   
 
*INFO  n.a.m.c.r.ProducerRegistryImpl - Registry register producer...*

but I can't find it in my logs =(